# Does Science Fiction and Fantasy have a mascot?

Tags: discussion

I'm just wondering on this but does this site have a mascot for this site. Anime & Manga.SE are planning and thinking of doing at least three site Mascots. I was just wondering if this site has a Mascot since this site isn't a Beta and has been around a lot longer than Anime & Manga.SE.

Just curious. Hope my question isn't silly. Thanks. :)

Comment: I think we should nominate 2 mascottes, one for Fantasy and one for Science Fiction.

Comment: What about the half-winged angel thingy in the background?

Comment: You should really consider Twilight Sparkle. One mascot that shares both science and magic traits.. :P

Comment: `I volunteer as tribute!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Harry Potter - The Sorting Hat]

*So put me on! Don’t be afraid!

And don’t get in a flap!

You’re in safe hands (though I have none)

For I’m a Thinking Cap!*

**I nominate the  Sorting Hat!**

<sub>Artist: Rose Ann Mary K</sub>
<sub>Red hand-drawn circles: Slytherincess</sub>
<sub>Note: The Sorting Hat is *not* a time-traveling robot, but it is 1000+ years old :P</sub>

Answer (score 10):

I was going to downvote [DVK's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3460/1359) for lack of [freehand red circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138032/166646), and then it hit me.

Our mascot should not be a time-traveling robot.  It should be: freehand red laser beams!

Examples:
[image]

[image]

Comment: what is that second picture from?

Answer (score 4):

It absolutely MUST be a time traveling robot.

[image]

Comment: Does he travel through time on the motorcycle? Or does he more, like, Apparate into the future or past? (I've never seen the *Terminator* series ... I know, I know ...)

Comment: @Slytherincess - Give back that geek hat.

Comment: @Slytherincess - Next you'll be telling me that you've never seen Star Wars...

Comment: @DVK -- I will *not*! *Terminator* is totally a man movie. Besides, why does he even need sunglasses when he has cyborg eyes or whatever ...

Comment: @Richard - I don't know who you are or where you came from, but from now on you'll do as I tell you, okay?

Comment: @Richard -- Obviously < looks up > you would be wrong ;)

Comment: @Slytherincess - He needs sunglasses because sunglasses are cool. It's the same reason he chooses the least efficient possible mode of transport.

Comment: @Slytherincess - I bet you *like* Jarjar

Comment: @Richard - Will you defer your motion, to allow a commission to explore the validity of your accusations? (Meesa pleads Not Guilty)

Comment: @Slytherincess - I was not elected to watch people suffer while you discuss Jarjar in a committee

Answer (score 1):

Did somebody say "time travelling robot"?

[image]

Comment: What is this from?

Comment: Dr Who. It's filled with little tiny people

Answer (score 1):

I vote for a (possibly time traveling) robot unicorn.
[Pick one](https://www.google.nl/images?q=mecha+OR+robot+unicorn).

It is both SF (robot) and F (unicorn).

And it has a [game](http://games.adultswim.com/robot-unicorn-attack-heavy-metal-twitchy-online-game.html)!

Comment: I am really fussy when it comes to unicorns.

Comment: @MiharuDante -- As one should be. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange mascot should obviously be...

### ...Handy, the Hand-Drawn Red Circle:

[image]

For more information, see [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9592/51226).

Comment: Needs more hand-drawn circles around it

Comment: @Valorum And done.

Comment: Now it needs some hand-drawn arrows pointing at the important features.

Comment: @Valorum The limbs are arrows.

Comment: Perhaps you could point them out so that that's a little clearer?

Answer (score 1):

What about the one-winged warrior angel lady from the header?  Does she have a name yet?

[image: one-winged warrior angel lady]

This is the part that @Valorum is referring to in the comments:

[image: angel with encircled posterior]

Comment: I never realised that she's actually standing on something, rather than flying.

Comment: Also, is it a she, or just a guy with a really nice butt?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  My daughter.

[image]

---

Capy Q. Stenchbeast-Cheber is already the Official (Unofficial) Dog of Mos Eisley, and she has agreed to run for "Official <del>(Unofficial)</del> Dog and Mascot of Mos Eisley".

---

Some of the Mos Eisley regulars have gone on record as saying that she's already the defacto mascot:

> *You'd have to vote to repeal at this point*
>   - [Mazura](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30579872#30579872)

And:

> [Jonah](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=29643064#29643064):  *Can I be the room mascot, then?*
>
> [Mazura](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=29643071#29643071):  *No, that's Capy.*

---

And it has been widely accepted that she is indeed the Mos Eisley dog:

> *Capy is Room Dog.*
>   - [Rand al'Thor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=30579890#30579890)

And:

> *Wad's dog, Capy is the real face of Mos Eisley*
>   - [Steelerfan](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=29994749#29994749)

And:

> *We have a room dog and a room ferret.*
>   - [Rand al'Thor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=30147278#30147278)

---

#### In short, if Mos Eisley is to have a mascot, I think it should be Capy (although I'm obviously the least impartial source imaginable, so it should be up to the community at large).

Comment: My cat DGAS. Plus one.

Answer (score -1):

I think site mascots (and especially *-tan* like mascots) are pretty ridiculous. But, I vote bees... thousands of bees.

Comment: Sorry, but the [bees are disappearing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI4Gbggxs8o).

Comment: Because *of course* there is a blog called [Weird Bee People](http://www.spicytec.com/2010/10/weired-bee-people.html) ... I've never thought about playing the clarinet while covered with 6 billion bees ... that really wouldn't have occurred to me.

Comment: [Gavotte](http://skin-horse.com/cast/)!